# Awk read 3 characters after a specific character

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have an output file which has a part shown below.

```
================================================================================
                                       INPUT FILE
================================================================================
NAME = t-Butylvinylidene-s.inp
|  1> ! LPNO-CCSD cc-pVTZ cc-pVTZ/C UNO TIGHTSCF TIGHTOPT Grid6 NOFINALGrid NUMGRAD PAL4
|  2> 
|  3> %geom Scan
|  4> A 2 1 15 = 67, 71, 10
|  5> end
|  6> end
|  7> 
|  8> *xyz 0 1 
|  9> 6        4.053878000    -18.527907000     -3.717354000
| 10> 6        3.588474000    -18.874154000     -5.083237000
| 11> 6        2.917226000    -19.112390000     -6.132425000
| 12> 6        2.817703000    -18.178677000     -2.886206000
| 13> 1        2.133454000    -19.025647000     -2.847879000
| 14> 1        3.094894000    -17.913405000     -1.866801000
| 15> 1        2.286657000    -17.336824000     -3.329174000
| 16> 6        5.010397000    -17.327109000     -3.786851000
| 17> 1        5.368223000    -17.071145000     -2.789879000
| 18> 1        5.877217000    -17.555623000     -4.406951000
| 19> 1        4.511903000    -16.455783000     -4.209438000
| 20> 6        4.792242000    -19.727095000     -3.102721000
| 21> 1        5.654756000    -20.005483000     -3.708269000
| 22> 1        5.149078000    -19.479242000     -2.103325000
| 23> 1        4.135842000    -20.593249000     -3.030303000
| 24> 1        4.320782000    -19.183475000     -5.923829000
| 25> *
| 26> 
| 27>                          ****END OF INPUT****
================================================================================
```

I want to read third and 3 last characters.

```
|  4> A 2 1 15 = 67, 71, 10
```

I had the code below to do this.

```
read -r -a scanopt <<< $(awk '
/INPUT FILE/ { input=1;}
input && 
/geom Scan/ {getline;gsub(",",""); print $3,$8,$9,$10,"T";exit}
' OFS="\t" "$path")
```

the input there is to make sure I find the right sentence, etc
My problem is sometimes the line can be different so the last 3 numbers which I need would be at a different positions! a few example are:

```
B 1 2 = 1.2, 2, 9
D 4 8 9 5 = 50, 60, 12
```

I need the 1st and the last 3 characters, first has a constant position so easy,... but the last 3, any ideas how to do this all I can think of is a big loop with lots of if's.

Another issue I want to consider, is that if in the input file somebody would enter the info in different ways as below:

```
 %geom Scan A 2 1 15 = 67, 71, 10
end
```

or

```
 %geom Scan 

A 2 1 15 = 67, 71, 10
end
```

so I actually need to process word by word from when I encounter `%geom scan` until `end`. now I'm doing it line by line!

Comment: The script seems to be looking for `INPUT FILE` and other things that are not shown in your example data.  Please make your script match your sample data so we have some chance of seeing what you are doing.  Either add more lines to the sample input, or (preferably) remove superfluous material from the script.  With the correct script and example data, please show the actual output and the desired output.

Comment: What would the output for the above be? `A 67, 71, 10`? Look for `/INPUT FILE/` then `/%geom/` then `/=/` (potentially on the same line as `%geom`. Then loop the fields looking for the `=` (or re-split the line with `FS="="` or similar).

Comment: I am thinking about it but would be a very dirty code.

Comment: I'm confused by 'third and last three characters'.  I suspect you mean 'third and last three fields', or, perhaps 'the number before the equals sign and the three numbers after the equals sign'. So, for the example line `|  4> A 2 1 15 = 67, 71, 10`, you want output as `15 67, 71, 10`, possibly with the commas missing — is that correct? Or are you interested in the letter and the three numbers after the equals sign?  Remember: when you ask a question on SO, you must make it possible for people who know nothing of your problem to understand what you want. Even as updated, this doesn't do that.

Comment: The last field is `$NF`. The second and third to last fields are `$(NF-1)` and `$(NF-2)`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean third and last three fields?

```
awk '{print $3, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

will do that.

for the other requirements I think this should work

```
awk '     /end/{f=0} 
   /%geom Scan/{f=1;sub(/^.*%geom Scan/,"")} 
        f&&NF>3{print $3,$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'
```

Updated to trim the header line and guard for field count.

Comment: it is the first after the '|  4>' numbering. and your code prints that two times in first line then prints another line with what I want.

Comment: changed first to third.

Comment: it prints " |  3>  | 3>
A 64, 69, 12"
in two lines it is just supposed to print the second line.

Answer (score 2):

The key is knowing what you can count on 99.9% and what you can't in the input. And also knowing that awk allows for picking off fields "from the end" as well.

It looks to me like you can always count on the lines of interest (and only those lines) to contain the pattern [digit][optional spaces][equal sign]. If that is true, this should work:

```
awk '/[0-9]\s*=/{print $3, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF, "T"; exit}'
```

For your second case, you'd add a second pattern *before* the one above (to catch it first):

```
awk '/%geom Scan .*=/{print $5, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF, "T"; exit}
     /[0-9]\s*=/{print $3, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF, "T"; exit}'
```